# how to create correct -journal file after editing sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have a `.db` file and i want to edit it using `sqlite editor` or other applications ready for editing databases.... inserting a new row in tables is successful and there is no problem, ....but after inserting, the `-journal` file which is attached to that databases will be removed.... i know `-journal` is a roll back for database... but i don't know how should i edit that database for creating that `-journal` file correctly?!!...

also sometimes inserting a new row in some tables in `.db` file cannot be successful and after exiting application it will be removed... it's a problem about `-journal` file or not??...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-journal` file is automatically handled by the database. You don't need to care about it.

It might be deleted or not depending on [some connection setting](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), but that is merely an optimization.

Comment: thanks... but when i insert a new row in some tables and save it, sometimes this new row will be deleted automatically and `-journal` file also deleted, so why this happens ??... it's not about journal file?

Comment: Apparently, whatever software you're using did not actually commit the changes.

Comment: i know there is some triggers in any .db file and according to these triggers, some table will be inserted from inserting on other table.... but when i insert into a table, second table will not be inserted... and if i insert to second table manually, it will be deleted...!!!...where is my mistake?(excuse me for my bad English)!

Comment: Ask a new question about those triggers.